# Rails Leaderboard Gem not working for TieRankingLeaderboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using this gem for leaderboard: 
https://github.com/agoragames/leaderboard

When I am using the normal leaderboard, it works:

```
def index
    highscore=Leaderboard.new('highscores')
    1.upto(10) do |index|
        highscore.rank_member("member_#{index}", Random.new.rand(1..100))
    end
end
```

However, when I am using other types of leaderboards it isn't working:

```
def index
    highscore=TieRankingLeaderboard.new('highscores')
    1.upto(10) do |index|
       highscore.rank_member("member_#{index}", Random.new.rand(1..100))
    end
end
```

I get error: `uninitialized constant ApplicationController::TieRankingLeaderboard`

which means that Rails is not detecting the class.

Comment: Are you asking how to fix a problem in some random code you don't own?

Comment: I wanted to know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: The library doesn't provide a code sample for the other types of leaderboard, unfortunately. But in the title you assert it's the library that's at fault anyways ;-)

Comment: How do you `require` the gem? In the source, all three classes are in separate files. The gem might simply be misconfigured, too.

Comment: I am using it in a Gemfile actually

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully should help others. I wasted considerable time figuring out this small thing.

You need to put

```
require 'tie_ranking_leaderboard'
```

in application.rb